# Ubuntu 22.04 keeps crashing with Firefox, Chrome and Brave browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, crash, brave

I had Ubuntu 22.04 for quite a while without major problems. I recently uninstalled snap because Ubuntu was getting sluggish. Now that snap is uninstalled, it is way more responsive. But today Ubuntu crashes and I have to re-login. It crashes without warning with a black screen. It happens when I'm browsing on Firefox, Chrome and Brave. It even crashed after clicking a web link. I red it was a OOMD problem but I'm not sure. Ubuntu 22.04 never did that for all the time I used it since the beginning. What's wrong with it?

Comment: This is very likely a hardware problem.

Comment: Could it be related to what this guy on the YT video explains? (OOMD) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XotltmuFUyU

Comment: Also when I install-uninstall packages, the terminal often says I have broken packages.

Comment: Today I had the same black-page-crash-to-login, by clicking a web link in Firefox. A pop up said: '' Could not connect to session bus: Failed to connect to socket/run/user/1000/bus: Connection refused.

Comment: Today I had the same black-page-crash-to-login, just by clicking a web link in Firefox. A pop up on the black page said: '' Could not connect to session bus: Failed to connect to socket/run/user/1000/bus: Connection refused'' . After closing the pop up: ''Could not acquire name on session bus''    Anyone knows what it means and how to fix that problem?

Comment: Check RAM with memtest.

Comment: Hi Pilot6. Thank you for your help. I just ran memtest for 30 minutes and passed completed without any errors. The crashes happens mainly when I'm clicking a link in my browsers. It reminds me Windows 95 blue pages...Why does Ubuntu crash? As I wrote, these crashes happened after I uninstalled Snap (terminal commands from a YouTube uninstall Snap video). Also my terminal reports broken packages when using it. Could it be related? I'm new to Ubuntu and need help.

Comment: Did you check RAM? It looks like a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0):

It used to happen a lot with me in brave and VSCode but then I tried some hacks and it actually worked.
first just update your snap packages using:

```
sudo killall snap-store

sudo snap refresh
```

By this all the packages will be updated to their latest versions. Another pattern which I noticed was that when I opened new tab/session in brave or VSCode, if I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key first then it used to close on it's own but if I just randomly click any other key and then press alt or ctrl then it doesn't  crash. Give it a try in case it works for you.

Comment: I have updated snap but Ubuntu continue to kick me out of the session, specially when I try to connect (every time I try to login to my Hotmail email online account). Recently Ubuntu gave me a new error: ''Could not connect to session bus: Failed to connect to socket/run/user/1000/bus: Connection refused....Could not acquire name on session bus'' Does anyone in the Ubuntu community knows what it means and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling hardware acceleration by going to Menu / Settings and search performance, turn off recommended performance settings then disable hardware acceleration.

Worked for me in AMD CPU / GPU.